# Why does adding a constructor break Angular 2 here?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am attempting to define a TypeScript class called `NavItem` that I want to hold a title and url. I find that if I define this class and instantiate it using object notation `{title: "foo", url: "bar"}` it works perfectly, but as soon as I add a constructor (even if I don't immediately use it) it completely breaks:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-item',
    templateUrl: './views/navitem.html',
})
export class NavItem {
    @Input() title: String = "default title";
    @Input() url: String;

    // if I comment the following out it works fine:
    constructor(inTitle: String, inUrl: String) {
        this.title = inTitle;
        this.url = inUrl;
    }
}
```

If I put the constructor in, I get this in my page:

> EXCEPTION: No provider for String! (NavItem -> String) in [navItems in TopNav@2:11]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I put the constructor in, I get this in my page:

This is because *angular* is supposed to *instantiate* the controller *for you*. You don't do `new FooController`, angular does. So any constructor parameters must have a corresponding provider registered with angular.

Comment: I see. I think my problem is I need to split up my model and view. I am treating `NavItem` as both a model and a view (a view with properties), and that seems to be a bad idea with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is used for DI with components. If you want to pass in the values of title and url you would do the following.

```
<nav-item [title]="Sometitle" [url]="http://someurl.com">
```

Angular will hook it up for you